# Custom filter function does not produce expected output

Tags: c, filter

I am trying to make a filter that prints on the screen only the data I want. Here's what I am talking about:

```
Cost* FilterSum(Controller* ctrl, int n)
{
    int i;
    DynamicVector* CostList=getAll(ctrl->repo);
    for(i=0;i<getLen(CostList);i++)
    {
        Cost* c=getElementAtPosition(CostList,i); //returns the element on one position
        if((c->sum)<n)
        {
            return c; //if the element(Cost in my case) has the sum<20 return it
        }
    }


return 0;
}
```

So, I have Dynamic Array with Costs as elements. If the sum of the cost is less than n(n is given from the keyboard) I want to print on the screen only those costs. :)
This are the print functions in the console:

```
void PrintCost(Cost* c) //this function prints one cost
{
    printf("\nID: %d\n", getID(c));
    printf("Day: %s\n", getDay(c));
    printf("Type: %s\n", getType(c));
    printf("Sum: %d\n\n", getSum(c));
}

void PrintCosts(Console* console) //this one prints all the costs in the list
{
    DynamicVector* CostList=getAllCosts(console->ctrl);
    if (getLen(CostList))
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<getLen(CostList);i++)
        {
            Cost *c=(Cost*)getElementAtPosition(CostList,i);
            PrintCost(c);
        }

    }
    else printf("No cost in the list!");
}
```

And here is the call function from controller in the console:

```
void FilterCostsBySum(Console* console)
{
    int n;
    printf("See the costs that have the sum less than: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Cost* c = FilterSum(console->ctrl,n);
    PrintCost(c);
}
```

Now, here comes the problem. If I have Monday with sum=10, Friday with sum=20 and Saturday with sum=40 and I want to print only those days with sum<30, it just prints Monday and that's it, it doesn't print Friday too. Where am I doing wrong? In the FilterSum function in the controller where I return the c? I tried everything and it didn't work at all... maybe you can help me! :)

Comment: *cough* code review *cough*

Answer (score 2):

It's only printing one because you're only executing the `PrintCost` function once after getting one of the valid costs via `FilterSum`. You need to make your `FilterCostsBySum` function loop and print costs pushed to a `DynamicVector`.

Write a function that returns a `DynamicVector` containing all the costs satisfying the condition you want. You would do this by changing the `FilterSum` function so that instead of returning one `Cost`, it would add any cost that satisfies a given condition to a `DynamicVector` and return it. Rename the function `GetFilteredCosts` afterwards.

Finally, inside the `FilterCostsBySum` function, you would loop over the elements in the returned `DynamicVector` and print the costs.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((c->sum)<n)
    {
        return c; //if the element(Cost in my case) has the sum<20 return it
    }
```

The `return` statements breaks the loop and exits the `FilterSum` function, so the function just returns the first `Cost` which matches the condition. You should change it to return a `Const**`, an pointer to a list of `Const *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((c->sum)<n)
{
  return c; //if the element(Cost in my case) has the sum<20 return it
}
```

This will immediately return only 10. 
Instead of immediately returning, add 10 to a list.
Then when you obtain 20, add it to the list. Once for loop in FilterSum() is done, then
you can return this list.